# Function doesn't return a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

```
const isName = req => {
    return user
        .find({ where: { name: req.body.name } })
        .then(row => {
            return row == null ? true : false;
        });
 };
```

Function `isName()` doesn't return a value. This simple code `row == null ? true : false;` doesn't return a value, but I'm sure that's working. What is the reason?

Comment: Is there any error in the console?Also how is  this function called in your app?

Comment: you return a promise, not a boolean. But it seems you actually return something.

Comment: Please add more info about how you are using the isName function. row == null ? true : false will return true or false, but isName wont (it return a Promise)

Answer (score 1):

Querying is asynchronous, so make sure you await for the result and send it:

```
// I guess it's a route handler
const isName = async (req, res) => {
    const result = await user
        .find({ where: { name: req.body.name } })
        .then(row => row === null); // same as row === null ? true : false;

     res.send(result);
 };
```

Comment: Your code make no diff from OP , both will return the same PROMISE.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :**

```
return user.find({ // <------ This will return promise not true or false
```

> So you can't make call like isName() and get expected result , promise
>   should be handled to get the expected result

**Solution :**

```
isName().then(isThere => { // <------- To get value you should handle like this
    if(isThere) {

    } else {

    }
})
```